# How to find equilibrium of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find equilibrium of following differential equations$$\frac{dU}{dt}=aV+bV-c\frac{UV}{U+V}$$$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-aV-bV+c\frac{UV}{U+V}$$

If we let these two equation equal to $0$, we get $(a+b)V=c\frac{UV}{U+V}$, I have no idea how to find the equilibrium, anyone could help me with this problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Something look very wrong about that system. Make sure you copy the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

$$\frac{dU}{dt}+\frac{dV}{dt}=0$$

So

$$U=-V+K$$

It reduces them to:

$$\frac{dU}{dt}=(a+b)(U-K)-c\frac{U(K-U)}{K}$$

Now, we have one equation one variable.